# Как отобразить скрытый дочерний элемент при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть теги `<h5>`, которые скрыты при помощи `display: none`.
Нужно чтобы при наведении появлялся тот элемент, на который навели, а не все элементы подряд.
Как можно такое сделать?

```
$('ul > li > a').mouseout(function() {
    $('ul > li > a > h5').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
});
$('ul > li > a').mouseover(function() {
    $('ul > li > a > h5').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
});
```

Comment: `console.log('this');` всегда выводит в консоль строку `this`

Comment: а зачем тут вообще яваскрипт?

Comment: @Grundy, потому, что `hover` на скрытых элементах не работает ;)

Comment: `скрыты при помощи display:block` - это круто.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, так и события тоже ведь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что элемент действительно скрыт через `display:block` ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще-то я был не прав. `hover` (как и события) действительно работают на оборачивающих тегах. А вот на `h5` ни первое ни второе не работает. Но это если я правильно угадал разметку по селекторам))

Comment: @korytoff, извините опечатка там display: none

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я вообще-то имел в виду, что навести мышку на скрытый элемент нельзя, поэтому ни псевдокласс `:hover`, на аналогичные джаваскриптовые события не возникнут. А вот про что ты сейчас, я не понял.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, логично что на h5 ничего не будет работать, пока оно скрыто

Comment: Фу.. Я наконец-то вопрос понял. Сейчас отвечу.

Comment: Может быть вам нужено свойство `visibility: hidden;` ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, опоздал :-D

Comment: Как же нынче сложно пробиться с правкой... Трижды не успевал применить правку, пока разные люди по частям то же самое делали.

Comment: @Regent, главное правильно выбрать вопрос :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В данном случае вам вообще не нужен JavaScript. Можно обойтись средствами CSS:

```
ul > li > a > h5 {
    display: none;
}

ul > li > a:hover > h5 {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Скриптом это делается так:

```js
$('ul > li > a').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('h5').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).children('h5').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
});
```

Но по-нормальному это надо делать без скрипта:

```
ul > li > a > h5 {
  display: none;
}

ul > li > a:hover > h5 {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: В первом js обработчике `$('ul > li > a > h5')` избыточно. Наверное правильнее сделать по аналогии со вторым

Comment: я бы предположил что все таки лучше `mouseenter` вместо `mouseover`

Comment: @Grundy, обновил

Comment: Ну и если уж придираться, то лучше `.hide/.show`  вместо редактирования CSS свойств

Comment: _The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events._

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, чем лучше? они ж внутри тот же css и вызывают

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну это смотря в каком случае. Конкретно здесь - без разницы.

Comment: @Grundy, он при `show` правильный `display` подберёт.

Comment: @Grundy, с ходу вижу два момента: 1. лучше читается. 2. не нужно править код, если эти блоки вдруг станут `display: inline`

Comment: @Qwertiy, правильный это какой? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, `block` или `inline` (или любой другой, что был до сокрытия)

Comment: @Grundy, вроде дефаултный для элемента. У спана будет `inline` у таблицы `table`, у скрипта... упс, `none` :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, "_ну это смотря в каком случае. Конкретно здесь - без разницы._", разница есть: вы сразу убираете потенциальные проблемы при переходе на `display:inline`. Ну и читаемость

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а ты в курсе, что в стандарт включили свойство `hidden`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, во-первых не нужно мне тыкать. Во-вторых, это не имеет особого отношения к приведенному вами коду. Вы же с `display` работаете.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev кстати, в jQuery 3.0 ведь ушли от использования `.hide()` и `.show()`. В данном конкретном случае с ними проблемы вряд ли будут, но, видимо, скоро "тренд" будет за `.css('display', 'block');`

Comment: @Regent, вряд ли за `.css('display', 'block');`. Cкорее уж за `removeAttr('hidden')`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, это свойство. `el.hidden = false` или `$(el).prop('hidden', true)`. Хотя с ним есть небольшая проблемка - по умолчанию у него приоритет меньше чем у css. Надо ещё `[hidden] { display: none !important; }` делать.